# Python lxml & string encoding issue

Tags: python, character-encoding, lxml

I'm using lxml to extract text from html docs and I cannot get some characters from the text to render properly. It's probably a stupid thing, but I can't seem to figure out a solution...

Here's a simplified version of the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>DAÑA – bis'e</p> <!---that's an N dash and the single quote is curly--->
    </body
</html
```

A simplified version of the code:

```
import lxml.html as LH
htmlfile = "path/to/file"
tree = LH.parse(htmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
for para in root.iter("p"):
    print(para.text)
```

The output in my terminal has those little boxes with a character error (for example,

[image]

which should be "– E"), but if I copy-paste from there to here, it looks like:

`>>> DAÃO   bisâe`

If I do a simple `echo` + problem characters in the terminal they render properly, so I don't think that's the problem.

The html encoding is UTF-8 (checked with `docinfo`). I've tried .encode() and .decode() in various places in the code. I also tried the lxml.etree.tostring() with utf-8 declaration (but then .iter() doesn't work ('bytes' object has no attribute 'iter'), or if I put it towards the endnodes in the code, the .text doesn't work ('bytes' object has no attribute 'text')).

Any ideas what's going wrong and/or how to solve?

Comment: Having coded a couple of basic websites myself, it  seems strange that these characters, ñ – etc, are in the source html in the first place. I would expect them not to render correctly in the browser, but they do. Maybe this is related to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file with the correct encoding (I'm assuming UTF-8 here, look at the HTML file to confirm).

```
import lxml.html as LH

with open("path/to/file", encoding="utf8") as f:
    tree = LH.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for para in root.iter("p"):
        print(para.text)
```

---

**Background explanation** of how you arrived where you currently are.

Incoming data from the server:

```
Bytes (hex)            Decoded as   Result String          Comment
44 41 C3 91 4F         UTF-8        DAÑO                   proper decode
44 41 C3 91 4F         Latin-1      DAÃ▯O                  improper decode
```

The bytes should not have been decoded as Latin-1, that's an error.

`C3 91` represents one character in UTF-8 (the Ñ) but it's two characters in Latin-1 (the Ã, and byte 91). But byte 91 is [unused in Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout), so there is no character to display. I took ▯ to make it visible. A text editor might skip it altogether, showing `DAÃO` instead, or a weird box, or an error marker.

When writing the improperly decoded string to file:

```
String                 Encoded as   Result Bytes (hex)     Comment
DAÃ▯O                  UTF-8        44 41 C3 83 C2 91 4F   weird box preserved as C2 91
```

The string should not have been encoded as UTF-8 at this point, that's an error, too.

The `Ã` got converted to `C3 83`, which is correct for this character in UTF-8. Note how the byte sequence now matches what you told me in the comments (`\xc3\x83\xc2\x91`).

When reading that file:

```
Bytes (hex)            Decoded as   Result String          Comment
44 41 C3 83 C2 91 4F   UTF-8        DAÃ▯O                  unprintable character is retained
44 41 C3 83 C2 91 4F   Latin-1      DAÃƒÂ▯O                unprintable character is retained
```

No matter how you decode that, it remains broken.

Your data got mangled by making two mistakes in a row: decoding it improperly, and then re-encoding it improperly *again*. The right thing would have been to write the bytes from the server directly to disk, without converting them to string at any point.

Comment: All indication that this is indeed utf-8 (in-doc meta tag, bash ```file -i```, and ```docinfo``` in the script). It makes perfect sense what you say, but still get the boxes. Is it strange that the ñ (for example) is directly in the html source code instead of &ntilde;? Maybe that's part of the problem.

Comment: No, that's not strange. HTML supports any character that the chosen file encoding can represent. `ñ` and `&ntilde;` are 100% the same thing, but the latter may be easier to enter when you don't have the right keyboard layout for typing an actual `ñ`, or when the chosen file encoding cannot represent the actual `ñ` (e.g. to get `ñ` into an ASCII-encoded file).

Comment: It's hard to say what encoding your file is in (it might already be broken depending on how the file was produced in the first place). Only looking at the bytes at the location in question can clarify this.

Comment: Files are scraped off the web, so I'm not really certain how they were made. If I print bytes instead of str, it's also not the correct characters. Is that what you mean by already broken? Since the characters render correctly if I open the html file in a text editor, I assume it can still be extracted correctly somehow....

Comment: You scraped them? How? And how did you save them? What does the text editor detect as the file encoding? Also, tell me the byte sequence at the offending position.

Comment: Maybe scraped isn't the right word: wget. Text editor shows UTF-8. Offending bytes - e.g. DAÑO = DA\xc3\x83\xc2\x91O, n-dash = \xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x93, cun'e = cun\xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x99e, straño = stra\xc3\x83\xc2\xb1o.

Comment: Yes, the file is already broken. Can you share the URL you have downloaded it from and the commandline you used to save it?

Comment: Here is what I think has happened during download. Originally the data was proper UTF-8, that got interpreted as Latin-1, that got written to file as UTF-8, and thus ended up garbled. Reading the file as UTF-8 cannot fix this. Quite possibly the error is on your side due to mistakes when saving the file that's why it's important to know how you did that. (It's possible to fix the file while reading it, but it's much more sensible to not break it in the first place)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your remarks! I used the command ```wget --recursive www.bondia.com/category/local```. The original URL is https://www.diario.aw/2019/12/5-ana-di-prison-exigi-pa-duo-cu-a-haci-asalto-arma-pafor-di-banco/

Comment: It still really gets my goat that these problem characters are rendered without issue in the source html.

Comment: Modern browsers have fallbacks for common errors, it's entirely possible that the browser bends over backward to correct mistakes such as this one.

Comment: I'll look into what's going on with this URL later.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts! A couple more pieces of info: If I download the same page via the browser using save as, the encoding is not broken. I used the same ```wget``` command on another website and there was no issue with encoding.
You said in another comment "it's possible to fix while reading it..." – do you have any suggestion how to do that? I tried reading the file as latin1, but it just spit out a different set of wrong characters and boxes.

Comment: That's what I suspected, the error is in how you handle the file, not in how the server sends it down the wire. There might be a mistake in the `Content-Type` header, that's why I want to double check the URL later. Are you using wget's `-o` parameter to save the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204082/discussion-between-tomalak-and-bob).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the `unidecode` package to work quite well converting non-ascii characters to the closest ascii.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
def check_ascii(in_string):
    if in_string.isascii():  # Available in python 3.7+
        return in_string
    else:
        return unidecode(in_string)  # Converts non-ascii characters to the closest ascii
```

Then if you believe some text might contain non-ascii characters you can pass it to the above function. In your case after extracting the text between the html tags you can pass it with:

```
for para in root.iter("p"):
    print(check_ascii(para.text))
```

You can find details about the package here: https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Comment: Thanks for answering. This works only in the sense that it gets rid of those ugly boxes, but the character rendering is still wrong. Ñ becomes A, ' becomes a, ñ becomes A+-, ndash disappears completely.

Comment: You don't want your file to be converted to ASCII.

Comment: I see, sorry about that, it might be a problem of the original source then. @Tomalak the idea was not to convert the file to ASCII but the extracted text